# How to make Orchard to have more than one pager on the custom page

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

Background: 
I have customize Content page by introducing a custom module.
Right now I have an obstacle to have tow pagers on the page at the header and at the footer of my content page. Strangely, Orchard allows only one pager on the page. Adding two @Display(Model.Pager) does not help.

Code:

```
@Display(Model.Pager)
 <fieldset class="contentItems bulk-items">
@Display(Model.ContentItems)
</fieldset>
@Display(Model.Pager)
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I think it's because you're actually using the exact same shape, and effectively adding it to the parent shape twice. The second one wins. Instead, you may want to have a separate parent shape (like a zone) and add the shape explicitly. I have a view for example where I'm doing this: `@Display(Model.Pager)` and later `Layout.AsideSecond.Add(Model.Pager);`

Comment: Tried but without success. I added what works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
    var pagerShape1 = Shape.Pager(pager).TotalItemCount(maxPagedCount > 0 ? maxPagedCount : query.Count());
    var pagerShape2 = Shape.Pager(pager).TotalItemCount(maxPagedCount > 0 ? maxPagedCount : query.Count());

    var viewModel = Shape.ViewModel()
                    .ContentItems(list)
                    .Pager1(pagerShape1)
                    .Pager2(pagerShape2)
                    .Options(model.Options)
                    .TypeDisplayName(model.TypeDisplayName ?? "");

    In view:

    @Display(Model.Pager1)
    <fieldset class="contentItems bulk-items">
        @Display(Model.ContentItems)
    </fieldset>
    @Display(Model.Pager2)
```